# Grails Find parent by child

Tags: grails

I look through the internet and I didnt find yet an answer for my question. Should be pretty easy:

```
class Parent {
  String name
  Child child
}
```

When I have a child object, how can I get the Parent by it?
like:

def Parent = Parent.findByChild(child)

How am I able to get a Parent object by it child?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where have you looked?

Are these domain classes?  If so, then you can connect them via has_many and belongs_to:

```
class Parent {
    String name
    List children
    static has_many = [ children: Child ]
}

class Child {
   static belongs_to = [ parent: Parent ]
}
```

Then you can just write `child.parent`

Comment: I have only the child, and I want to know whose its parent. So something like def Parent = Parent.findByChild(child). and the parent has only one child, and yes its both domain classes. I actually need a "select" method to get the parent by sending it a child

Comment: Forget about it, i was mistyping the findBy.

So that code I just put works
Child child = ....
def parent = findByChild(child)
Thanks for your attention kevin

Comment: It's more common to write these as hasMany and belongsTo

Answer (score 0):

`def parent = Parent.findByChild(child)` works fine - you can use dynamic finders for scalar fields (strings, numbers, booleans, etc.) and other objects.

Doing the reverse and finding all `Child` instances for a given `Parent` is a little more involved but can be done with HQL:

```
def p = Parent.get(id)
def children = Parent.executeQuery(
       'select c from Child c, Parent p where p.child=c and p=:parent',
       [parent: p])
```